# Set-Acl. Some or all identity references could not be translated. XML.config

Tags: xml, powershell, acl

I need some help with my PowerShell Script to change NTFS Permissions with `Set-Acl`. I already got this.
It works as soon as I have only one id in the list. As soon as I have more than 1 id I always get this error:

> Some or all identity references could not be translated.

XML File:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Pfade>
  <pfad id="1">
    <name>d:\Freigabe</name>
    <gruppe>Admin</gruppe>
    <rechte>FullControl</rechte>
    <aktion>allow</aktion>
    <rechtsetzen>Add</rechtsetzen>
  </pfad>
  <pfad id="2">
    <name>d:\Freigabe</name>
    <gruppe>Jeder</gruppe>
    <rechte>Modify</rechte>
    <aktion>deny</aktion>
    <rechtsetzen>Add</rechtsetzen>
  </pfad>
  <pfad id="3">
    <name>d:\Freigabe\Ordner</name>
    <gruppe>SYSTEM</gruppe>
    <rechte>FullControl</rechte>
    <aktion>allow</aktion>
    <rechtsetzen>Add</rechtsetzen>
  </pfad>
  <pfad id="4">
    <name>d:\Freigabe\Ordner</name>
    <gruppe>Admin</gruppe>
    <rechte>Modify</rechte>
    <aktion>allow</aktion>
    <rechtsetzen>Delete</rechtsetzen>
  </pfad>
  <pfad id="5">
    <name>d:\Freigabe\TEst</name>
    <gruppe>Jeder</gruppe>
    <rechte>Modify</rechte>
    <aktion>allow</aktion>
    <rechtsetzen>Delete</rechtsetzen>
  </pfad>
  <pfad id="6">
    <name>d:\Freigabe\TEst</name>
    <gruppe>Admin</gruppe>
    <rechte>FullControl</rechte>
    <aktion>allow</aktion>
    <rechtsetzen>Add</rechtsetzen>
  </pfad>
</Pfade>
```

PowerShell:

```bsh
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
$scriptpath = $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
$dir = Split-Path $scriptpath
cd $dir

$doc = [XML](Get-Content -Path struktur.xml)

[array]$arrayid = $doc.Pfade.pfad.id

for ($i=0; $i -lt $arrayid.count; $i++) {
    New-Variable -Name "arrayid$i" -Value $arrayid[$i]
}

$path = $doc.Pfade.pfad
$pathname = $doc.Pfade.pfad.name
$pathgruppe = $doc.Pfade.pfad.gruppe
$pathrecht = $doc.Pfade.pfad.rechte
$pathaktion = $doc.Pfade.pfad.aktion
$pathrechts = $doc.Pfade.pfad.rechtsetzen

foreach ($i in $arrayid) {
    $FolderName = $pathname
    $acl = Get-Acl $FolderName
    $acl.SetAccessRuleProtection($True, $False) #?
    $rule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($pathgruppe, $pathrecht, "ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit", "None", $pathaktion)
    $pathgruppe
    switch ($pathrechts) {
        Add {$acl.AddAccessRule($rule)}
        Delete {$acl.RemoveAccessRuleAll($rule)}
    }
    Set-Acl $FolderName $acl
}

Get-Acl $FolderName | select Path, Owner, Group, AccessToString | Format-List
cd $dir

Remove-Variable array*
```

Error Message:

```
Ausnahme beim Aufrufen von "AddAccessRule" mit 1 Argument(en): "Manche oder alle
Identitätsverweise konnten nicht übersetzt werden."
In D:*********.ps1:32 Zeichen:13
+        Add {$acl.AddAccessRule($rule)} 
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : IdentityNotMappedException

Ausnahme beim Aufrufen von "RemoveAccessRuleAll" mit 1 Argument(en): "Manche oder
alle Identitätsverweise konnten nicht übersetzt werden."
In D:*********.ps1:33 Zeichen:16
+        Delete {$acl.RemoveAccessRuleAll($rule)} 
+                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : IdentityNotMappedException

Set-Acl : AclObject
In D:*********.ps1:35 Zeichen:1
+ Set-Acl $FolderName $acl 
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (System.Object[]:Object[]) [Set-Acl], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SetAcl_AclObject,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetAclCommand
```

Could someone help please?

Comment: I changed a lot in this Script but got another problem.

So if someone need a script like that look [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41680708/set-folder-subfolder-and-file-permission-set-acl-powershell-script-setting-fil](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41680708/set-folder-subfolder-and-file-permission-set-acl-powershell-script-setting-fil) and maybe you'll find the error that i can not find

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `$path*` variables contain arrays with all values from the respective nodes in your XML, but the [`FileSystemAccessRule`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.accesscontrol.filesystemaccessrule.aspx) constructor expects a single identity reference for each rule.

Pipe `$doc.Pfade.pfad` into a `ForEach-Object` loop and put the rest of the `$path*` variable assignments inside the loop:

```
$doc.Pfade.pfad | ForEach-Object {
    $pathgruppe = $_.gruppe
    $pathrecht  = $_.rechte
    $pathaktion = $_.aktion
    $pathrechts = $_.rechtsetzen
    $FolderName = $_.name
    ...
    Set-Acl $FolderName $acl
}
```

Also, your `for` loop and `$arrayid*` variables are pointless. Remove them.

Comment: Thank you very much